# How to stop spring 3.2.3 to block my cross domain requests

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, sesame

I have a standard spring rest api, which for some of its functionalities
have to call another rest api (SESAME). When this request is made, spring 
prevents the request which causes the SESAME httpclient to throw this:

```
  org.openrdf.http.protocol.UnauthorizedException
    at org.openrdf.http.client.SparqlSession.execute(SparqlSession.java:1056)
    at org.openrdf.http.client.SparqlSession.executeOK(SparqlSession.java:1003)
    at org.openrdf.http.client.SesameSession.getServerProtocol(SesameSession.java:205)
    at org.openrdf.repository.http.HTTPRepository.useCompatibleMode(HTTPRepository.java:310)
    at org.openrdf.repository.http.HTTPRepositoryConnection.begin(HTTPRepositoryConnection.java:156)
    at com.project.dao.impl.SparqlCommandDaoImpl.save(SparqlCommandDaoImpl.java:58)
    at com.project.service.impl.CommandServiceImpl.save(CommandServiceImpl.java:20)
    at com.project.controller.BasicController.saveCompany(BasicController.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:849)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.project.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:27)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:146)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:277)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The request does not reach the SESAME endpoint.I tried [this](http://zhentao-li.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/enable-cors-support-in-rest-services.html) solution, but without success. The same error countinues to appear. Tests that uses the same functionality with pure DAO, without spring controllers, works fine. My question is, how to prevent/stop spring to block my cross domain requests. Security is not an issue.

Comment: I'm no Spring MVC expert, but IMHO it is unlikely that this is related to CORS headers, since they are a mechanism to allow browsers to do _Javascript_ cross-domain HTTP calls. This error occurs when executing a Java webapp, where the same-origin policy is not normally enforced. What is the precise Sesame Server URL this is trying to connect to? Do the Sesame Server logs or the Tomcat logs (assuming you're running Sesame on Tomcat) contain any errors or warnings for the request attempt?

Comment: I use port forwarding to access my SESAME endpoint and I connect to it on http://localhost:9000 providing and the repository id to HttpRepository constructor. The log remains silent on this request. It does not reach the endpoint. As I stated it works when I use  Sesame API + spring wiring and the trouble comes when I use spring controllers.

Comment: The `UnauthorizedException` indicates that your client tries to do a request but that the server responded with a '401 Unauthorized' error. If there's nothing in the tomcat logs, it means something else in the server request handling chain (e.g. whatever proxy you use to handle port forwarding) intercepted it to throw this error.

Comment: You are right. Incorrect wiring that skips the username and password.